# Problems installing gdal ( Geospatial Data Abstraction Library) binary files on Centos

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, gdal

I tried installing the gdal rpm package (www.gdal.org).  I installed using sudo yum install gdal and then went to use one of the gdal utilities (gdal_translate) and get the following error message:

```
gdal_translate: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: atom_obj_cache
```

What does this error mean? libgdal.so.1 is part of gdal-libs which is a rpm package also installed with the yum install.  I tried to do the command:

```
rpm -q -R gdal-libs|grep atom_obj_cache
```

and get nothing.  What is atom_obj_cache and how can I resolve this issue to ensure a successful run of gdal_translate?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same error on CentOS 7.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

GDAL is part of the EPEL repository and the base Centos repo.  I would stick with them.  If you need more recent builds, then the ELGIS repo can give you more recent builds with additional packages like QGIS (RHEL 6, not 7).

- http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS

That said, this appears to be an issue relating to you trying to open a file whose driver is not installed.  What is the file or file type you are trying to translate?  Another test to try is to print info about the file using `gdalinfo`.

Next, there are multiple packages for gdal.  Here are a few with my RHEL 7 box

- gdal-devel
- gdal-doc
- gdal-java
- gdal-libs
- gdal-python
- gdal

Try installing the `gdal-python` and `gdal-devel` to see if this gives you the additional shared objects.